# jquery, how to animate element after being sure that it's not being animated at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$("sth").not(':animated').animate();
```

hey

is this the best way to animate element after being sure that it's not being animated at the same moment ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you want, yes. Though I am curious what the `sth` selector is :)

```
$("#id:not(:animated)").animate(); // Is another way to write it
```

Or if you simply want to stop it before it animates again, use `stop()`:

```
$("#id").stop().animate();
```